# How to turn a bootstrap box class to also a button class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button

Boostrap newbie here!, i found this example that displays tiles on a web page. i need to be able to click on one of these tiles (with the visual effect-behavior as if they were a button). so they can lead me to another webpage etc...

I would appreciate any help.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 2em auto;
}
.cols {
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-gap: 3%;
    -moz-column-width: 30%;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 3%;
    -webkit-column-width: 30%;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 3%;
    column-width: 30%;
}
.box {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height:100px;
    background:#BFBFBF;

}
</style>


<div id="container" class="cols">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put each `class="box"` into an `<a>` tag(apply the box styles to these instead) & redirect them using the `href` attribute. This has nothing to do with button or bootstrap

Comment: can you provide me with a one line sample? thank you for your reply. also it has to appear as a button

Comment: What do you mean "appear as a button", you mean it should just be clickable right?

Comment: yes, forgive me for not being specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No change in the CSS. You need to change your HTML to wrap your `<div class="box"></div>` within an `<a>`.

```
<div id="container" class="cols">
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </a>
  ..other boxes..
</div>
```

Obviously `href` value can be changed for what you want. Wrap all your box like in the snippet shown below

```css
#container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 2em auto;
}
.cols {
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-gap: 3%;
    -moz-column-width: 30%;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 3%;
    -webkit-column-width: 30%;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 3%;
    column-width: 30%;
}
.box {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height:100px;
    background:#BFBFBF;

}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="cols">
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please note that this is **invalid HTML** as `a` is **not allowed to contain block level elements as long as it has `display: inline;`**.